# Controller cannot access to table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie in Rails and I'm developing an app with 3 controllers/models: Doctors, Patients and reports. Doctor has many Patients, Patient belong to Doctor, Patient has many Reports and Reports belongs to Patient.

To create a Patient from the outside through the API I have this in the controller:

```
def create                                                                                  
  if doc=params[:patient]                                                                                                                                         
    doctor_id=doc[:doctor]                                                                  
  else                                                                                      
    puts 'NO PARAMS' =># this is just to monitor the status in the server                                                                       
  end                                                                                       
  doctor=Doctor.find(doctor_id)                                                             
  @patient=doctor.patients.new(                                                             
                          name:                   doc[:name],                               
                          email:                  doc[:email],                              
                          sex:                    doc[:sex],                                
                          password:               doc[:password],                           
                          password_confirmation:  doc[:password_confirmation])              

    if @patient.save                                                                        
       render json: { success: true, data: @patient.remember_token, status: :created }      
     else                                                                                   
       render json: { success: false, data: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end                                                                                    
end
```

This works as expected: from the params I can retrieve the doctor_id and create a new patient related to him.

But the strange thing came out when I do exactly the same with reports. In my controller I have:

```
def create                                                                                    
  par=params[:report]                                                                         
  token=par[:patient_token]                                                                   
  pat=Patient.find_by_remember_token(token)                                                   
  puts pat                                  =>#this is to monitor the server                                                  
  last_report=pat.reports.last                                                                
  puts last_report                          =>#this is to monitor the server                                                  
  if ((Time.now-last_report.created_at)/86400).round>0                                        
    report=create_report(par[:patient_token])                                                 
    report.attributes=par                                                                     
    if report.save                                                                            
      render json: { success: true, data: report, status: :created }                          
     else                                                                                     
       render json: { success: false, data: report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }    
     end                                                                                      
  else                                                                                        
    last_report.attributes=par                                                                
    if last_report.save                                                                            
      render json: { success: true, data: last_report, status: :created }                     
     else                                                                                     
      render json: { success: false, data: last_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end                                                                                      
  end
end
```

And this time server crashes and don't retrieve the Patient. pat=nil so pat=Patient.find_by_remember_token(token) don't works.

Does anyone can figure out why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION:

First of all thanks all for your clues it guide me to the solution. Thanks to debugger gem I could see that the token that "really" was sent to Patient.find_by_remember_token(token) was wrong in a manner. I mean. I was catching the token on the server through

puts token => which return "X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA" (correct token)

BUT through debugger I realize that the real token that was sent was

"\"X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA\"" which is definitely a wrong one so I modified my curl query in next way:

```
ORIGINAL CURL:  curl -X POST -d 'report[patient_token]="X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA"&repo

MODIFIED ONE:  curl -X POST -d 'report[patient_token]=X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA&repo
```

And then it works... damn 5 hours of delay.

Thanks all!!

Comment: does par[:patient_token] is present?, what's its value is?

Comment: Yes it is, value: "X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA"

Comment: so its clear that no patient with this remember_token exists in your database.

Comment: Nop.It exist. 1.9.3p448 :001 > Patient.find_by_remember_token("X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA")
  Patient Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."remember_token" = 'X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA' LIMIT 1
 => #<Patient id: 2083, doctor_id: 12, name: ["Adelia", "O'Hara"], age: 37, sex: "male", email: "cameron.hegmann@schuster.net", phone: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$PkzQOdfkIzHQHfrjJ6xWVe57dUbWyhxfB6SNQ6m.elEP...", day_active: nil, remember_token: "X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA", created_at: "2013-08-10 14:57:22", updated_at: "2013-08-10 14:57:>

Comment: (they are fake Patients, but it exist)

Comment: On the server I get "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms"

Comment: try putting debugger just before this specific line in controller.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie, how can I do this?

Comment: hi, please post the full backtrace

Comment: using debugger http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug and  https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: Thanks man! debugg helps to solve the issue. I'm gonna update the post to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this for searching `Patient.where(:remember_token => token)` this should work.

Comment: Nop. It doesn't. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you verified in the database that the data for that particular token exists?

Comment: Yes I did. 1.9.3p448 :001 > Patient.find_by_remember_token("X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA") Patient Load (1.4ms) SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."remember_token" = 'X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA' LIMIT 1 => #<Patient id: 2083, doctor_id: 12, name: ["Adelia", "O'Hara"], age: 37, sex: "male", email: "cameron.hegmann@schuster.net", phone: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$PkzQOdfkIzHQHfrjJ6xWVe57dUbWyhxfB6SNQ6m.elEP...", day_active: nil, remember_token: "X6MlhaRLFMoZRkYaGiojfA", created_at: "2013-08-10 14:57:22", updated_at: "2013-08-10 14:57:> –

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
def create
 token = params[:report][:patient_token]
 if token
   pat=Patient.find_by_remember_token(token)                                                   
   puts pat                                  =>#this is to monitor the server                                                  
 else
   puts "No params"
 end
end
```

This way you will be able to know, if your token is coming in request or not. Hope it will help. Thanks